# Save Excel file as CSV via Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, openpyxl

> Language: Python 3.8
> Platform: MacOS 11 | Windows 10
> Filetypes: .xlsx | .csv.
> Task: File/Format Conversion

**Synopsis:** My excel file has cells with functions/formulas. I want to save this file as a .csv while preserving the value of the formulas (not the actual string of the function, itself)

**What works:** Pause script, prompt user to open Excel > 'Save As' .csv // Excel processes the functions within the cells and preserves the values before saving as .csv

**What hasn't worked:** Using pandas or openpyxl to convert the excel file to a .csv (such as 'wb.save' and 'df.to_csv' // The produced .csv file does not process the function cells and instead outputs nothing within those cells.

**Question:** Anyway of leveraging excel's 'process the function and save the values' function within the Python script?

Thank you!

**Sample Code - Pandas**

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

**Sample Code - Openpyxl**

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb.active
with open('file.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
c = csv.writer(f)
for r in sheet.iter_rows():
c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
wb.save('file.csv')
```

**Sample Problem**

Excel Columns:

```
A: ['First Initial']
B: ['Last Name']
C: ['Email']
```

Formula in all rows within column C:

```
C1: [=CONCATENATE(A1,".",B1,"@domain.net")]
C2: [=CONCATENATE(A2,".",B2,"@domain.net")]
C3: [=CONCATENATE(A3,".",B3,"@domain.net")]
etc.
```

Output of 'file.xlsx' through excel & 'file.csv' (via excel > 'Save As' .csv):

```
A1: ['j']
B1: ['doe']
C1: ['j.doe@domain.net']
```

Output of 'file.csv' after following the Pandas Sample Code:

```
A1: ['j']
B1: ['doe']
C1: ['']
```

if a cell does not contain a formula, the conversion outputs correct values within the cells. For the cells with formulas, the cells are empty (since .csv is just plain-text). Is there a way to replicate excel's behavior of running the functions first > save output value into cell > save as .csv?

**UPDATE:**

So I found the issue, although not sure how to go about solving this. Pandas works as intended when I created a fresh .xlsx and tried the sample code. But it didn't work with the .xlsx in my script - and I narrowed it down to this step

The following is a snippet from my script that copies values from one excel file into another:

```
wb1 = xl.load_workbook('/file1.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.load_workbook('/file2.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.active

mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value


wb2.save('file2.xlsx')
```

The file ('file2.xlsx'), while seemingly opens and functions just like a regular excel file, DOES NOT preserve its values within cells that have formulas after converting it to a .csv via pandas.

The file ('file1.xlsx') however, does this just fine.

BUT, if I open 'file2.xlsx' and just simply save it (without changing anything), and then try converting it via pandas - it DOES end up preserving the values within formulas.

So there's definitely something wrong in my code (surprise, surprise) that does this. Not sure why, though.

Comment: If you only want to save an excel file as a csv then you don't need python, so can you explain why you want to do this with python?

Comment: @TaxpayersMoney It's part of a larger workflow - but I've excluded that information to simply focus on the file conversion. The product of the workflow should output a .csv (currently outputs a .xlsx) - that's the part I am trying to change. It can be done manually, but the whole point is to automate the process - and there are multiple .xlsx files that need to be turned into .csv files - the constant "Save As" process defeats the purpose of automating the task.

Comment: Couldn't you read the excel file as a pandas dataframe and then output to csv using read_excel and to_csv?

Comment: @TaxpayersMoney You are correct - that process does work. There's a flaw in another part of my code where the xlsx in need of conversion is a product of a value transfer from one workbook to another. This is where the problem happens (see updated part of my question). Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: Use read-only mode and stream to CSV row for row. Much faster than going via Pandas.

Comment: @CharlieClark Could you elaborate on that? I've used data_only for Pandas, but that drops the formula cells all together.

Comment: There's not much to elaborate: you read the rows in openpyxl, read-only, values-only and write them at the same time to CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I was able to solve my own question - posting it here for anyone else who has a similar issue (searching this problem led me believe ya'll exist, so here you go.)

> Note: This only works on a Windows system, with Excel installed

```
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from win32com.client import constants as c

    excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application') # Calls Excel
    excel.DisplayAlerts = False # Disables prompts, such as asking to overwrite files
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("/file.xlsx") # Input File
    wb.SaveAs("/file.csv"), c.xlCSV) # Output File
    excel.Application.Quit() # Close Excel
    excel.DisplayAlerts = True # Turn alerts back on
```

Comment: FYI it's much simpler to use Pandas library to load an excel workbook and then save to csv.

Comment: Is this faster than pandas conversion?any ideas?

Comment: This code's not as pretty but it feels much faster than importing the CSV library and running a loop to import each line one by one.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Pandas library.
Here ,this might help :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-excel-to-csv-in-python/

Comment: While this works, it doesn't work if your excel file includes cells with working functions.

Comment: @TheCrazySwede - then your `read_excel` call is failing, because `to_csv` certainly works. Which is why we need an actual [reprex].

Comment: @BigBen Updated the question with more info. The 'to_csv' works perfectly fine for everything, except every cell containing a formula comes out as blank. The rest of the cells are saved as intended.

Comment: @TheCrazySwede - unable to reproduce: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YansM.png What version of pandas?

Comment: @BigBen You are right! Found the part of my code that is causing this issue. I updated the end of the question - would you be willing to help?